# Is zero a valid value for a CUDA device pointer?

Tags: cuda

Can a CUdeviceptr be set to zero (NULL) to indicate an uninitialized pointer, or can zero be a valid device pointer under any circumstances?  And further, is it allowed to pass a null device pointer to cuMemFree?  I'm assuming that this is analogous to how it works in C(++), but I haven't been able to find any documentation substantiating this.  I'd like an answer that refers to some kind of credible source, if possible.

EDIT: What want to know if it's guaranteed that I can write code like this:

```
CUdeviceptr p=0;

[... do something else, maybe allocate memory for p ...]

if (p != 0) {
     cuMemFree(p);
     p = 0;
}
```

Or even better without the `if` statement, like I can do with `delete`.  Or do I have to keep track of the allocation status of `p` by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 0 is a guaranteed-invalid value for CUdeviceptr.

I am not sure cuMemFree(0) has always been valid, but in CUDA 4.0 cuMemFree(0) returns CUDA_SUCCESS.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't know if it is documented anywhere.  All I know is that while working on the CUDA driver (which I did from pre-1.0 to 4.0), we took measures when implementing cuMemAlloc() specifically to prevent it from passing back 0 when a valid memory allocation had been performed.

Answer (score 1):

The 0 address isn't a C++ feature - it is a hardware feature.
The CPU prevents access to address 0 and raises an interrupt.
The 0 address is an invalid address in the GPU too.
Try passing 0 to cuMemFree, you should get a [error code](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__TYPES_g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038.html#g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038) as a result.

Comment: But C++ explicitly allows calling delete with a null pointer (3.7.3.2) - it will have no effect.  I had hoped for it to be the same in CUDA.  But if zero is an invalid address that is good enough for me, do you have a source for that?